# Moment JS, first day of actual week is incorrerct

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to get first day (monday of actual week (today is Sunday, last day of the week)) using:

```
dateFrom = moment().day(1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But it returns:

```
Start date range is: 2014-11-10
```

But it should be

```
  Start date range is: 2014-11-3
```

How can i solve it please and what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moment.js first day of the week incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080927/moment-js-first-day-of-the-week-incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that Sunday (0) is the first day of the week. So today we are in the week 2014-11-09 to 2014-11-16. You request the Monday (1) of that week, which is 2014-11-10.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/

Try this:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/

```
moment().weekday(0)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks but how can i change this behaviour? I need always first day as monday of actual week.

Comment: I solved it using: var begin = moment(date).startOf('week').isoWeekday(1);